# Can I create a new and clean account without getting it merged with this account?

Tags: support, multiple-accounts

I want to create a new account on Stack Overflow, starting from scratch, focusing it on other kinds of questions. I dont want to merge my two accounts; I want to have the two accounts.

It is legal and safe to have them in Stack Overflow? Can I be sure that the accounts wont be merged?

Comment: so, i can create the other account and acces both accounts under the same Ip and navigator?

Answer (score 1):

As long as there won't be any illegal behaviour, I believe you can. I see no problems with it. I have such accounts, one of them is [AlieN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3520500/alien). I don't vote for myself, don't answer my questions asked by that account, in other words, I keep them parallel for 10 months already.

Comment: so, i can create the other account and acces both accounts under the same Ip and navigator?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 This might trigger auto-merge, better use different browser for each, or  use one of them only while in private/incognito mode. Better be safe than sorry. :)

Comment: @Sha didn't trigger in my case btw.